# Specified Cast not valid on a data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` and have assigned a cell click event to handle cell buttons. Now, this was working before; while I was working with other codes within the solution, I have not checked to see if those buttons are consistently working, till I found out that it is now giving an exception upon clicking a cell button:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred.
>   Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

```
var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            //locate the id row and column of the grid
            int Coordinate;
            Coordinate = (int)dgvItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
            var GetSORepoRow = GC.CSHR_SORepo.Where(s => s.id == Coordinate).FirstOrDefault();

            // Change Quantity Button
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewRow)
            {
                QuantityUpdate(Convert.ToInt16(GetSORepoRow.id), Convert.ToInt16(GetSORepoRow.Quantity));
                this.Refresh();
                txtboxSearchItem.Focus();
            } //. . .
```

Please, do ask me question for additional info.

Comment: Does the first cell in the row you indexing have an int? Could it be a header or footer?

Comment: which cast is invalid. DataGridView or int?

Comment: When debugging, you should be able to tell where and what is happening within those lines of code.  Which cast is failing?

Comment: @VincentFaller Yes, an id primary key (bigint) and Qantity(int). Those are the only ints there. I haven't changed data types in my SQL DB or in my Data Source/set though. Just added 2 columns which I'm not sure if it affects anything.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It is highlighting int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL type bigint converts to C# as Int64 or long.

Comment: There you go, I thank you very much. I will keep this in mind.